# Interchanging Limit and Integration, Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I am wondering if it is allowed to interchange the limit and integral sign in the following expression:
$$\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-N}^{N} b_ke^{ikx} \varphi(x) dx.$$

Here, $\varphi$ denotes a Schwartz function in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} b_ke^{ikx}$ denotes the Fourier transform of a periodic continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi.$ By definition $b_k:=\int_0^{2\pi}f(y)e^{iky}dy.$

Unfortunately, the usual theorems like dominated or monotone convergence can't be applied here. But my feeling is that the limit above should equal to
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} b_ke^{ikx} \varphi(x) dx$$

How can this be justified? Thank you for your support.

Comment: Maybe try to show that the integrand is smooth enough.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that the Fourier series is not differentiable in the classical sense. The function $f$ is continuous and periodic, thus the series converges only almost everywhere to $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral and the limit can indeed be interchanged.
To see this, first note that if $g \in L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Bbb{R})$ is $2\pi$-periodic, then
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\Bbb{R}}
    g(x) \, \varphi(x)
  \, d x
  & = \sum_{k \in \Bbb{Z}}
        \int_{2\pi k}^{2\pi k+2\pi}
          g(x) \, \varphi(x)
        \, d x \\
  & = \sum_{k \in \Bbb{Z}}
        \int_{0}^{2\pi}
          g(x) \, \varphi(x + 2\pi k)
        \, d x \\
  & = \int_0^{2\pi}
        g(x) \, P \varphi (x)
      \, d x,
\end{align*}
where $P \varphi(x) = \sum_{k \in \Bbb{Z}} \varphi(x + 2\pi k)$ is bounded
(since $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function) and $2\pi$-periodic.
The interchange of the series and the integral above can be easily justified using the dominated
convergence theorem.

Now, define $f_N := \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{k=-N}^N b_k e^{i k x}$, and note that
$f_N \to f$ in $L^2([0,2\pi])$.
Since $P \varphi \in L^\infty([0,2\pi]) \subset L^2 ([0,2\pi])$, we see
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\Bbb{R}}
    f_N (x) \, \varphi(x)
  \, d x
  & = \int_0^{2\pi}
        f_N (x) \, P \varphi (x)
      \, d x \\
  & \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \, P \varphi (x) \, d x \\
  & = \int_{\Bbb{R}}
        f(x) \, \varphi(x)
      \, d x ,
\end{align*}

which is what you wanted to show.

Comment: Phenomenal! Thank you so much.